# Django Error during template rendering In template ... error at line 0

Tags: django, django-admin, django-model, django-filter

Пишу сайт на Django по книги Дронова. Использую Django 3.0. И в главе 2.7 "Наследование шаблонов" вылезает ошибка:

Error during template rendering In template C:\Python\Django 3\samplesite\bboard\templates\layout\basic.html, error at line 0
Reverse for 'by_rubric' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['bboard/(?P<rubric_id>[0-9]+)/$']

что делать, и как может быть ошибка в строке 0?

Basic.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Главная{% endblock %} :: Доска объявлений</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
    <h1>Объявления</h1>
</header>
<nav>
     <a href="{% url 'index' %}">Главная</a>
    <a href="{% url 'add' %}">Добавить</a>
    {% for rubric in rubrics %}
    <a href="{% url 'by_rubric' rubric.pk %}">{{ rubric.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
</nav>
<section>
 {% block content %}
 {% endblock %}
 {% block paginator %}
 {% endblock %}
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html:

```
{% extends "layout/basic.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for bb in bbs %}
<div>
    <h2>{{ bb.title }}</h2>
    <p>{{ bb.content }}</p>
    <p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' bb.rubric.pk %}">{{ bb.rubric.name }}</a></p>
    <p>{{ bb.published|date:"d.m.Y H:i:s" }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block paginator %}
    {% if page.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }}">&lt;</a>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    {% endif %}
    Часть №{{ page.number }} из {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}
    {% if page.has_next %}
    &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}">&gt;</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.core.paginator import Paginator
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

from .models import Bb
from .models import Rubric
from .forms import BbForm

class BbCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/create.html'
    form_class = BbForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rubrics'] = Rubric.objects.all()
        return context

def index(request):
    bbs = Bb.objects.all()
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(bbs,5)
    if 'page' in request.GET:
        page_num = request.GET['page']
    else:
        page_num = 1
    page = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics,'page': page, 'bbs':page.object_list}
    return render(request,'bboard/index.html',context)
def by_rubric(request,rubric_id):
    bbs = Bb.objects.filter(rubric = rubric_id)
    rubrics = Rubric.objects.all()
    current_rubric = Rubric.objects.get(pk=rubric_id)
    paginator = Paginator(bbs, 5)
    if 'page' in request.GET:
        page_num = request.GET['page']
    else:
        page_num = 1
    page = paginator.get_page(page_num)
    context = {'bbs': bbs, 'rubrics': rubrics, 'page': page, 'bbs': page.object_list,'current_rubric':current_rubric}
    return render(request,'bboard/by_rubric.html',context)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Bb(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Товар')
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True,
                               verbose_name='Описание')
    price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Цена')
    published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True,
                                     verbose_name='Опубликовано')

    rubric = models.ForeignKey('Rubric', null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name = 'Рубрика')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Объявления'
        verbose_name = 'Объявление'
        ordering = ['-published']

class Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, db_index=True, verbose_name='Название')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Рубрики'
        verbose_name = 'Рубрика'
        ordering = ['name']
```

Ошибка вылезает при переходе на страницу http://127.0.0.3:8000/bboard/?page=2. Там применяется пагинация. До того как я начал писать шаблоны с наследованием всё было нормально, ошибка появилась в разделе 2.7 .

[image: django]

Comment: где то вы обращаетесь не к рубрике. добавьте вью и модели, чтобы точно сказать где вы ошиблись

Comment: если точнее, в bb.rubric.pk или rubric.pk не получаете id

Comment: @ZaArs добавил код models.py и views.py

Comment: @ZaArs как может быть ошибка в строке 0?

Comment: шаблон не отрендерился, там бывают такие ошибки

Comment: @ZaArs всё равно не работает, я даже пагинацию убрал

Comment: Все по книге проверил

Comment: проверьте примером из  ответа, если я прав, у вас будет исклбчение

Answer (score 0):

`rubric = models.ForeignKey('Rubric', null=True,...`

Вот здесь вероятно и есть проблема - у вас может не быть рубрики. Убедитесь, что у выводимого `bb` есть рубрика, а потом выводите ссылку. Либо замените ваш

```
<p><a href="{% url 'by_rubric' bb.rubric.pk %}">{{ bb.rubric.name }}</a></p>
```

на что то вроде

```
{% url 'by_rubric' bb.rubric.pk as bb_rubric_url %}
{% if bb_rubric_url %}
<p><a href="{{ bb_rubric_url">{{ bb.rubric.name }}</a></p>
{% else %}
Нет связи с рубрикой
{% endif %}
```

`else` добавлен чисто чтобы вы увидели, где проблема